# How to Auto-complete the TextBox while typing? Limited to 3 words?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have the following words that I want to select:

```
string standard = "select a part of the text in the textbox";
```

When someone types any letter in the string above, select 3 words at a time until the end is reached.

For example, the person typed the letter "o", so I'm going to select the first letter "o" plus 3 words ahead until I complete it.

[image]

I made a script using the event `PreviewTextInput` and the problem is that it cannot capture the typed space and also when I type a letter in the textbox, it is repeated in front and does not select the rest of the 3 words.

CS

```
string typed = "";
private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    string standard = "select a part of the text in the textbox";

    typed += e.Text;

    this.textBox1.Text = typed;

    int indexOf = standard.IndexOf(typed, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (indexOf >= 0)
    {
        string start = standard.Substring(indexOf + typed.Length);
        string[] s = start.Split(' ');

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < 3) this.textBox1.Text += $"{s[i]} ";
            else break;
        }
    }
    this.textBox1.Focus();
    this.textBox1.SelectionStart = typed.Length;
    this.textBox1.SelectionLength = this.textBox1.Text.Length - typed.Length;
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="18" Margin="143,107,0,0" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="308" PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput"/>    
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If I take the same **[code](https://pastebin.pl/view/870871d7)** as above and put it in `Windows Forms` in the `KeyPress` event method, it will work. But why doesn't it work in `WPF`?

How can I make sure that while I type a word in the textbox, do the AutoComplete in real time?

Comment: I found this article https://wpf.2000things.com/2012/09/03/638-previewtextinput-is-not-fired-in-many-cases/ and maybe you should play with another event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set e.Handled = true in your PreviewTextInput handler. "Preview" means that you will get a chance to do something before the TextBox is changed. Setting e.Handled to true will prevent Input events to change the TextBox.

```
        e.Handled = true;
```

Comment: it worked! now I'm going to have to put one more KeyDown event to capture the space